# Filter list where nested attributes match condition

Tags: scala, reduce

I have the following case classes:

```
case class Reduction(value: Int, label: String)
case class Variant(id: String, name: String, reductions: List[Reduction])
case class Item(id: String, name: String, variants: List[Variant])
```

I get a `List[Item]` out of a parsed JSON. Now I would like to filter every variant out, which has a reduction that does not match a specific reduction label.

Imagine it with the following example:

```
List(
  Item("1234", "Train ticket from A-B",
    List(
      Variant("1","short way", List(Reduction(50,"Half Fare"), Reduction(0,"Adult"))),
      Variant("2","long way", List(Reduction(0,"Adult")))
    )
  ),
  Item("5678", "Train ticket from B-C",
    List(
      Variant("1","short way", List(Reduction(50,"Half Fare"))), 
      Variant("2","long way", List(Reduction(0,"Adult")))
    )
  )
)
```

What I need in the end in form of a `List[Item]`:
all the items, which have a variant that holds a given reduction. E.g. if I need to filter "Half Fare", I expect the filtered List[Item]containing
Items 1234 with just Variant 1 and Item 5678 with just Variant 1. The filtering only has to happen on the variant level.

I know I have to work somehow with `fold` or `reduce`, but I am struggling with getting the code running.

My attempt looks somewhat like this:

```
items.reduce(i => i.variants.reduce(v => checkLabel(v.reductions, requiredLabel) )
```

As I am new to Functional Programming, I am hereby asking for advice on how to solve this properly. Any explanation would help.

Comment: One more question, you want the items that have at least one variant with at least one reduction matching your search. However, it is not clear if you want to filter out the reductions and variants that didn't matched or preserve all.

Comment: I would like to filter out those variants not having at least one correct reduction.

Comment: So, you want to filter the variants of each item, but no items theyselves? Also, if a variant has at least one valid reduction, you want to keep all those reductions or just the reduction that applied?

Comment: What should happen if there is an item without a matching `Variant`? Should it just clear all variants? Or should it clear the item?

Comment: @TomerShetah clear the item

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I would like to keep all those reductions

Comment: Remo I see. I updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to keep the items with no matching variant, you can do:

```scala
val requiredLabel = "Half Fare"
items.map(item =>
  item.copy(variants = item.variants.filter(_.reduction.exists(_.label == requiredLabel)))
).filter(_.variants.nonEmpty)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/v3CqB5DgSiarFcmgQpoxbg/4).

Comment: I am still not sure if items without variants should be removed or just leave empty, OP requirements are a bit confusing. But I believe this should be enough for him / her to finish in case there is a misinterpretation, that is why I up voted it.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I asked this on the question. It is a bit confusing, but the OP answered: `@TomerShetah clear the item`

Comment: Yeah I saw that, I guess we have different interpretations of _"clear the item"_ :p

Comment: Actually I thought on both :) but then I decided that dropping the item makes more sense than clearing the item from its variants. Although I completely agree it is not clear at all.

Comment: @TomerShetah Much appreciated - this should help a lot! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Emjoy @Remo!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use something like this:

Considering the following case classes from the example:

```
case class Reduction(value: Int, label: String)
case class Variant(id: String, name: String, reduction: Reduction)
case class Item(id: String, variants: List[Variant])
```

You can to it as follows on `items: List[Item]`:

```
items.filter(_.variants.exists(variant => checkLabel(variant.reduction, requiredLabel)))
```

It's hard to understand what you meant, but this one filters all the items which contains some variant which `checkLabel` returns true for them

Try to change it for your specific usage or edit the post with clear further details, I will try to assist :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This more or less solves my problem. Only thing is that reduction is also a list -> a variant can hold multiple reductions. I'll update my questions.

Comment: So the `json` is misleading since each Variant can have a single reduction by the json format (Its not array), anyways - glad its helped

Comment: yeah, just realized this was a mistake. Updated the question now :)